# Time Complexity for C Program Which uses Random Numbers

Tags: c, time-complexity

I don't know if this has been asked but consider the below program.

**Doubt 1**

Can I calculate an approx. complexity for this program ? (worst/best/avg.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int no;
    while((no=rand()))
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613886/shuffle-elements-of-an-array-n-numbers-uniformly-randomly-possibley-in-expected) question OP has calculated the complexity of a problem which uses random numbers, but i don't know how to do this calculation.

In Java the random gen. would take O(1) regardless of the seed.

Would this program have a constant time complexity (as it doesn't depend on any other factors/inputs)?

<strike>**Doubt 2**</strike>

```
int main()
    {
        while(1){
           //some action
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Complexity for this problem?

Does infinite loop make the problem deterministic?

Comment: There is no input to this program. How could this have a time complexity figure then? Another grasp: time complexity is for **deterministic** algorithms. Of course, easy random is not that random most of the time, but then again: I would not call it deterministic if the iterations depend on a (pseudo) random value.

Comment: @ppeterka66 Should i keep the question open ? or delete it?

Comment: There is no input at all. It is possible to estimate the complexity of the function rand(), but not of the program itself, because its duration depends on a random seed.

Comment: Actually I don't know if it should be closed or not. Would someone profit from reading this? Or would one even be able find it if in need of this information? Frankly, I'm at a loss on _this_ question...

Comment: @ppeterka66: time complexity of randomized algorithms is equally important as for deterministic ones.

Comment: @larsmans thinking of it a bit: yes it is true. With a bit of knowledge on probability calculus (where I might fall short, to be honest), it seems to be totally meaningful too... It might not mean anything for a given run on a particular input, but with an arbitrarily large number of runs and inputs, it gets a meaning. Hey, randomized algorithms just started interesting me! Also, we'd have to have quite some knowledge of the probabilistic characteristics of the random function used I think.

Comment: @ppeterka66: even for deterministic algorithms, proving average time complexity usually requires probability theory :)

Comment: If you consider the number of times you select `no` as an input and you write the code like this `while(rand() != no)` the algorithm is O(n) as stated here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the implementation of `rand`. Only if it's implemented in such a way that every one of the `UINT_MAX` possible random seeds (or at least all the possible return values of `time`) hits zero at some point, is worst-case time complexity even defined. Otherwise, it's undefined because this is not an algorithm but a semi-algorithm at best: it's not guaranteed to terminate.

The actual complexity, then, can I think only be determined by considering a series of machines, with ever larger `sizeof(time_t)`, since `time` is the only part of the program that takes any input. It's O(2^n) where n is the wordsize of the machine, since no more than that number of random seeds can exists.

On any single machine, the worst-case running-time is bounded above by some constant (which may be very large) under the assumption that `rand` will eventually hit zero for every seed, making it trivially O(1).

Comment: And what is your take on the fact that this program does not have any input? I think in this case, there is no meaning for complexity. If you disagree, would you elaborate on this?

Comment: @ppeterka66: `time` takes input.

Comment: Ok, point taken. What is the input length? How can you have different input lengths to this algorithm? Please don't take this personally, or as an attack of any kind, just trying to broaden my sight on something that seems utterly disturbing to me...

Comment: @ppeterka66: actually, that's a very good question. I'm going to change my answer, hang on.

Comment: It's still O(1) or meaningless--depending on whether rand() produces numbers from a repeating sequence that includes 0 or not.

Comment: ...because no matter what the size of time() return might be, srand() is only going to use a fixed number of bits from it.

Comment: @MikeHousky I think larsmans meant the srand() implementation to "grow" in the series of machines too

Comment: @MikeHousky: see refined answer. And yes, I assume `unsigned int` to grow with `time_t`. C integer sizes are fixed per implementation, but unbounded in principle.

Comment: @larsmans I get the point, and my theoretical half is smiling big, though my practicality-oriented half still feels that while it is true, didn't get us anywhere... Thanks for broadening my (our) sight!

Comment: As I said above, this program has one input the number Zero.

Comment: @ppeterka66: it's a pretty academic exercise, I'll give you that :)

Comment: The complexity of the program is based on the number of times the while loop is entered. Agreed? Zero might just as well have been an input to the program. Agreed?

Comment: @user814064: I don't follow. The program loops until `rand()` is zero. If a program takes an integer `n` and loops `while (n--)`, you wouldn't say its only input is 0.

Comment: I posted the while loop I was referring to above. Let's assume that the programs takes a series of numbers where no takes on the values 0,1,2,3 and compares using `while(rand() != no)` The program would be O(n). Assuming that the loop terminates (rand() eventually is `no`) the fact that it is using random numbers is COMPLETELY irrelevant to its complexity.

Comment: @user814064: on any single machine, yes.

Comment: @larsmans @user814064 : Agreed that the `rand()` method makes the program NON-DETERMINISTIC. Let me change the condition then. Let the new `while` be `while(1)` what about now? Does it make it deterministic? Is the complexity computable now?

Comment: I decided what I thought made sense. Then I found a reference to back it up and posted it above. Maybe the wikipedia entry is wrong -- but I'm not sure that that comment section here is the best place to argue it. I googled it `"Las Vegas algorithm:" random"` there's 168,000 entries.

Comment: @user814064 : Thanks for the link! The code in the question is Las Vegas agreed. Now my question is, consider an infinite loop what type of problem is that? AFAIK an infinite loop is not Random.

Comment: I didn't understand -- sorry! If you have something you want to know -- post a question.

Comment: It a REAL bad idea to edit the question so that people's answers no longer match.

Comment: @user814064 Pls check the ques. under NEW QUESTION

Comment: @boxed__l: never ask a new question under an old one. It defeats the FAQ nature of SO. To answer the question, that program has no complexity because it's not implementing an algorithm.

Comment: @larsmans : thanks! will keep that in mind. What if the body does perform some operation or follows some algorithm? Am i missing something very basic here about algorithms/complexities?

Comment: @boxed__l: it doesn't matter. A program that never terminates is not an algorithm, per definition.

Comment: @larsmans : Thanks again!!. Regarding "ask a new question under an old one", how should i tackle this? That second question struck me in the comments section so i modified the question as a new question seemed to be a time consuming process.

Comment: @boxed__l: asking a new question is the way to go, esp. after you've already accepted an answer. My answer no longer reflects your question, which is a bit of a shame.